# Why does 'p:ajax update' fail to update a p:tree?

Tags: primefaces

I want to produce the result that whenever a tree node is expanded any previously expanded sibling node is collapsed.

Below are my page and my bean. The onNodeExpanded method is invoked when a node is expanded; the System.out statements produce the expected results. However, the node upon which setExpanded(false) is executed remains expanded on the page.

I added a commandButton so that I could force an update of the tree. Pressing it results in the page properly displaying the node that was previously collapsed by the ajax event listener.

**The Page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>
        <title>PrimeFaces Tree: Ajax Update Problem</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body> 
        <h3>PrimeFaces Tree: Ajax Update Problem</h3>

        <h:form>
            <p:tree id="tree" value="#{problemController.root}" var="node" dynamic="true" orientation="horizontal">
                <p:treeNode>
                    <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
                </p:treeNode>

                <p:ajax event="expand" listener="#{problemController.onNodeExpanded}" update="tree" />
            </p:tree>

            <h:commandButton value="Update" immediate="true">
                <f:ajax render="tree" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**The Bean:**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.primefaces.event.NodeExpandEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultTreeNode;
import org.primefaces.model.TreeNode;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class ProblemController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private TreeNode root;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);
        TreeNode node0 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0", root);
        TreeNode node1 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1", root);

        TreeNode node00 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0", node0);
        TreeNode node01 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.1", node0);

        TreeNode node10 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.0", node1);

        node1.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.1"));
        node00.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0.0"));
        node00.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0.1"));
        node01.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.1.0"));
        node10.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.0.0"));
        root.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode("Node 2"));
    }

    public TreeNode getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public void onNodeExpanded(NodeExpandEvent event) {
        TreeNode expandedNode = event.getTreeNode();
        System.out.printf("Expanded %s\n", expandedNode);

        TreeNode parent = expandedNode.getParent();
        if (parent != null) {
            for (TreeNode sibling : parent.getChildren()) {
                if (sibling.isExpanded() && sibling != expandedNode) {
                    sibling.setExpanded(false);
                    System.out.printf("Collapsed %s\n", sibling);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Java 1.8  PrimeFaces 6.1  Mojarra 2.3  Weld 3.0

**Update 1**

I have updated the page with the code that @Kukeltje provided. Unfortunately, the siblings of expanded nodes are not being collapsed. I added a statement to the closeOthers function that logs to the console: the data ("root", or "0", or "0_1", etc.) of any node that I expand is displayed (as expected).

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>PrimeFaces Tree</title>
</h:head>
<h:body> 
    <h3>PrimeFaces Tree</h3>

    <h:form>
        <p:tree id="tree" widgetVar="treeW" value="#{testController.root}" var="node" orientation="horizontal" selectionMode="single">
            <p:treeNode>
                <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
            </p:treeNode>

            <p:ajax event="expand" listener="#{testController.onNodeExpanded}" oncomplete="closeOthers(this, PF('treeW'))"/>
        </p:tree>

        <h:outputScript>

        //<![CDATA[

        function closeOthers(current, widget) {

            var dataRowkey = $.urlParam(decodeURIComponent(current.data),current.source+"_expandNode");
            var selector = "li[data-rowkey='"+dataRowkey+"']";
            console.log("Collapsing siblings of " + selector);
            $(widget.jq).find(selector).siblings().find("span[aria-expanded='true']").siblings(".ui-tree-toggler").trigger("click");

        }


         $.urlParam = function (query, name) {
            var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(query);
            return (results !== null) ? results[1] || 0 : false;
         }

        //]]>

        </h:outputScript>

        <h:commandButton value="Update" immediate="true">
            <f:ajax render="tree" />
        </h:commandButton>

    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, most likely you do not save the state of the node somewhere and it is just fully rendered again (scope of the bean e.g.)? Please, learn how to create a [mcve] when posting a question. It makes it much easier when trying to help since we do not have to start guessing or asking or...

Comment: Any progress???

Comment: @Kukeltje I updated the question with an MCV example. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I found the reason/explanation. Will write an answer tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: Awesome! Thx, man.

Comment: It is not a direct solution on what you want to achieve rather an explanation to the question in the title

Comment: @Kukeltje Do you have any thoughts on a fruitful approach?

Comment: BTW: I suspect that what is happening is this: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2277. The client/server side trees have already synchronized prior to the event listeners being invoked. I'm attempting the remedy proposed there.

Comment: Don't think it is related. WilWill write something up tonight. Totally forgot. Thing is you cannot use Ajax on the tree and at the same time update the whole tree or even something aroubd it. You'll see more if you remove dynamic=true

Comment: The issue is indeed related but it is not about selecting/unselecting or hiding/unhiding, it is because of updating the component itself from within an ajax call in the component. Your issue can be fixed with some additional client-side javascript....

Comment: I read the issue more carefully now (was not really awake last night). It is indeed more related then I initially thought and the 'solution' in the end is where I was/am going as well. Part of the answer already posted. Will post the related client-side javascript later today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very common to update a full component from within ajax calls inside the component itself. Due to you using `dynamic="true"` you see less downside effects than without using `dynamic="true"`. The same will happen if you update a container around the `p:tree`. There are effectively 2 updates on the tree that sort of conflict with eachother, especially when there is some additional hiding of nodes being attempted.

What you effectively seem to be trying to achieve is to have just one node open at a time by using server side manipulation of the tree (which in itself is not wrong). This is related indeed what is attempted in https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2277 as well but that issue is too narrowly formulated since it is not about selecting/unselecting or like you experience hiding/unhiding, but the more general issue of not being able to update the full tree component from within an ajax call in the component.

Updating things server-side so a full refresh is still supported should still be done. But instead of doing an `update="tree"`, you can try to use the `oncomplete` javascript callback to close all other nodes client-side.

Adding the following javascript will do this for you:

```
<h:outputScript>

//<![CDATA[

function closeOthers(current, widget) {

    var dataRowkey = $.urlParam(decodeURIComponent(current.data),current.source+"_expandNode");


    //For a vertical tree:      
    //var selector = "li[data-rowkey='"+dataRowkey+"']";
    //$(widget.jq).find(selector).siblings().find("span[aria-expanded='true']").siblings(".ui-tree-toggler").trigger("click");


    //For a horizontal tree
    var selector = "td[data-rowkey='"+dataRowkey+"']";

    // The first attempt was to look for aria-expanded=true but we
    // found that sometimes it would be present on a collapsed node (bug?).
    // $(widget.jq).find(selector).parent().parent().parent().siblings().find("td[aria-expanded='true']").find(".ui-tree-toggler").trigger("click");

    // Searching instead for the minus icon did the trick
    $(widget.jq).find(selector).parent().parent().parent().siblings().find(".ui-icon-minus").trigger("click");

}


 $.urlParam = function (query, name) {
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(query);
    return (results !== null) ? results[1] || 0 : false;
 }

//]]>
</h:outputScript>
```

Then

- Give your widget a widgetVar e.g. `widgetVar="treeW"`
- add an oncomplete in the `p:ajax` like so `oncomplete="closeOthers(this, PF('treeW'))"`
- **REMOVE** `dynamic="true"` **OR ADD** `cache="false"` (bug I found, then it will only work once for each node, https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3668)
- **REMOVE** `update="tree"`

So the html ends up like:

```
<p:tree id="tree" widgetVar="treeW" value="#{problemController.root}" var="node" orientation="horizontal">
    <p:treeNode>
        <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
    </p:treeNode>

    <p:ajax event="expand" listener="#{problemController.onNodeExpanded}" oncomplete="closeOthers(this, PF('treeW'))"/>
</p:tree>
```

Comment: I'm thinking of tryiing to make a 'patch' for the tree component so you can configure an 'always-open-single node' so it becomes part of the component!